# Group list-of-tuples by second element, take average of first element

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

I have a list of tuples (x,y) like:

```
l = [(2,1), (4,6), (3,1), (2,7), (7,10)]
```

Now I want to make a new list:

```
l = [(2.5,1), (4,6), (2,7), (7,10)]
```

with the **new list having the average of the first value (x) of tuples if there are more than one tuple with the same second value (y) in the tuple.**

Here since for (x,y) = (2,1) and (3,1) the second element in the tuple y=1 is common therefore the average of x=2 and 3 is in the new list. y=1 does not occur anywhere else, therefore the other tuples remain unchanged.

Comment: Why did you tag pandas but give list-of-tuples (instead of dataframe) as input? pandas Dataframe works much better. Native Python lists have very limited capabilities for processing tuples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you tagged `pandas`:

```
l = [(2,1), (4,6), (3,1), (2,7), (7,10)]
df = pd.DataFrame(l)
```

Then `df` is a data frame with two columns:

```
    0   1
0   2   1
1   4   6
2   3   1
3   2   7
4   7   10
```

Now you want to compute the average of the numbers in column `0` with the same value in column `1`:

```
(df.groupby(1).mean()     # compute mean on each group
   .reset_index()[[0,1]]  # restore the column order
   .values                # return the underlying numpy array
 )
```

Output:

```
array([[ 2.5,  1. ],
       [ 4. ,  6. ],
       [ 2. ,  7. ],
       [ 7. , 10. ]])
```

Comment: could you explain a little whats happening in the code?...I am new to pandas

Comment: Sure, see update. If you still find it hard to follow, I recommend separate the chain command and print output of each.

Comment: what is the [[0,1]] doing? I know its reversing the order of the columns but how is it doing that?

Comment: without it, the data will appear as `column 1, column 0`.

Comment: yes i know that..I am asking how is it happening? how is it reversing ?

Comment: It's similar to slicing in `numpy`. In fact I believe it is `numpy`'s slicing as DataFrame is a subclass of numpy array.

Comment: @smci honestly I didn’t have the faintest idea about `ungroup`.

Comment: @smci can you provide any references?

Comment: @QuangHoang: sorry I'm an idiot, `.reset_index()` is correct. (I confused pandas with R). But I was wondering if the `[0,1]` was avoidable.

Comment: @smci yes, without it [[0,1]], the dataframe is ordered as `[1,0]` since `1` was the index.

Answer (score 0):

First form a hashtable/dict of all the second elements as key and their corresponding value as a list of values. Then with a listcomp you can get the desired output by iterating over the items of the dict.

```
from collections import defaultdict
out = defaultdict(list)
for i in l:
    out[i[1]] += [i[0]]
out = [(sum(v)/len(v), k) for k, v in out.items()]
print(out)
#prints [(2.5, 1), (4.0, 6), (2.0, 7), (7.0, 10)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way using `groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby

# Sort list by the second element
sorted_list = sorted(l,key=lambda x:x[1])

# Group by second element
grouped_list = groupby(sorted_list, key=lambda x:x[1])

result = []
for _,group in grouped_list:
    x,y = list(zip(*group))
    # Take the mean of the first elements
    result.append((sum(x) / len(x),y[0]))
```

You get:

```
[(2.5, 1), (4.0, 6), (2.0, 7), (7.0, 10)]
```

Comment: `for _,group in groupby(...)` is almost always avoidable and always bad idiom. Also worse performance on large dataframes.

Comment: Never heard of that. Do you have any post / reference for that?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method using `numpy.bincount`. It relies on the labels being nonnegative integers. (If this is not the case one can do `np.unique(i, return_inverse=True)` first).

```
w,i = zip(*l)
n,d = np.bincount(i,w), np.bincount(i)
v, = np.where(d)
[*zip(n[v]/d[v],v)]
# [(2.5, 1), (4.0, 6), (2.0, 7), (7.0, 10)]
```